# iOS - Any advice in order to debug NSUserDefault crashes during an Update

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsuserdefaults, updates

We have released an update on the AppleStore, in order to fix some bugs.

We have a lot of users crashing when they launch the App after updating the App.

If they uninstall the App and download it again, everything work fine.

After analyzing some crash reports and Crashlytics dashboard, we came to the conclusion that one specific library from our App is checking/setting the "First Launch Date" in the NSUserDefault.

This, plus the fact that after uninstalling/installing everything works fine, I deduced the issue came from the NSUserDefault.

I have a few questions that came to my mind, and I am in a hurry I don't know what to do.

What can I achieve in order to fix it?

- I didn't manipulate the NSUserDefault during the development between the 2 updates.
- Can I make a "diff" of the database in order to compare the state and any modifications that could occur between those updates ?
- Should I reset the database ?
- We can't reproduce the crashes (despite the majority of our users experimented a crash after the first install) and Testflight is not representative of a real update situation, because all our testers validated the update, with no issues at all.
- The solution that came to my mind is to release a new update from the previous version from the store, but how can I be sure the NSUserDefault won't make crashing the App during this "roll back".
  I mean if the issue came from the state of the database or a nil
  value. The library is 2 years old and not updated anymore, but we
  never experienced any crashes from this library.

I will take any advice/informations to get things done and clean.

Comment: You have a Git or something to manage your code, no? Remove your app from your device, check out the branch/commit, go back to the version released, install it on your device, go back to the last updated one, launch it again with Debugger. I'd recommend to have to clone in order to reproduce it more quickly (one on the last version, one on the previous one).

Comment: I had faced the same issue once, the problem is there was one library  named `RMMapper` I used in my code to store custom Objects in `NSUserDefaults`. The crash was because of getting nil value in a bool.

Comment: Can I do it with ipa file, we use Jenkins and Git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to swizzle `NSUserDefaults` methods to try catch or at least log problems. You could swizzle `-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]` and check whether the input is safe/sane and discard it if not.

Comment: The library is wrapped and integrated as a .a file, I just have headers, I can't access the code where they setObject. Your solution will allow me to swizzle synchronize and get an insight of what is set/get even outisde my code ?

Comment: I suggest to swizzle `setObject:forKey:` instead. And yes, that will give you insight into what gets stored into user defaults and when, no matter who calls it.